# Displaying images in textArea globally Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, dom, textarea

Is there a way for me to post an image in an arbitrary textArea on a site i.e Reddit/Stackoverflow and display for everyone? Right now I can traverse the DOM and have images display for myself but I want everyone to see it.

Is this possible??
Thanks

Comment: Textarea does not allow images. An image that is uploaded and posted on Reddit/Stackoverflow's servers is visible to everybody

Comment: Images you upload will be visible to all on these sites.

Comment: I want to write a script that allows me to post an image as a comment on a thread. I then would want that image within the comment and visible to everyone who reads the comment

Comment: You mean a bookmarklet?

Comment: ^ Not exactly. I'm making custom emojis as images and I want people to able to see them when I post them. How do I post the image in a textArea using a script? Is there a library for that? Is it possible? etc cheers